# MvvmCross-ColorPlugin: not working in Touch device

Tags: plugins, colors, touch, converters, mvvmcross

I'm having a weird trouble to make the ColorPlugin works in my Touch project.

Well, in my .Core project I created the following converter:

```
public class BoolToColorConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, object>
{
    protected override object Convert (bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var mvxColor = value ? new MvxColor (0, 255, 0) : new MvxColor (255, 0, 0);;
        try
        {
            var nativeColorConv = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNativeColor>();
            return nativeColorConv.ToNative (mvxColor);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            var exception = e;
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

And then i'm using it perfectly in .Droid project with:

```
local:mvxBind="TextColor ConnectionStatus, Converter=BoolToColor"
```

For this, I added the MvxPluginConverter as reference in the .Droid project.

But then in the .Touch project, I also added the MvxPluginConverter as reference, and in the bind:

```
set.Bind (connectionStatusLabel).For (l => l.TextColor).To (vm => vm.ConnectionStatus).WithConversion ("BoolToColor");
```

It is still working great . But only in the iPhone Simulator. In my device I'm receiving the warning in ApplicationOutput and it is not working at all:

```
Failed to create target binding for binding BackgroundColor for ConnectionStatus
```

Any clue in what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in regard,
Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all 'it doesn't work on the device' issues are due to the Xamarin linker stripping out symbols. Which symbols are being removed might become clear by looking at the full trace (it's not clear from this single line included in the question).

There are several mechanisms to help ensure the symbols are included - including command line switches, xml file, `Perserve` attributes and the `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` files  (which is the approach I generally use).

For more on this area try searching for e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmvvmcross%5D+not+working+on+the+device